# Search a url for unique phrase using Google API

Tags: http, web-crawler

Does Google have an API with a function which will verify if a specific phrase can be found at a given url?

Say I have a webpage url: *www.mysite/2011/01/check-if-phrase-exists*

I want to know if the phrase **foobar** exists somewhere on that document (it can be anywhere on the html document - not just "readable text").

The function/api would return True or False.

**Question Update**  The "method" should avoid me from having to retrieve the entire page to my server and search myself.  It is the fetching of the webpage to my server that I am trying to avoid (to cut down on bandwidth).

Comment: Have you checked the google API documentation?

Comment: Google Analytics has so many APIs; was hoping someone would point me to the right one.

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with app engine?  M. Schenkel, you mention "my server" in a comment - is your program running on app engine or your own servers?

Comment: On my server.  What I am doing right now is making my own http requests, getting the contents of the page, and then searching to see if the phrase is there.  I was wondering if Google had any such service.  This would allow me to "offload" this high bandwidth operation.  Instead I just pass the url and the phrase I am searching for.  And the API will return true or false.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they do, but you could do this yourself without much code (this is adapted from the [App Engine docs](https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html)):

```
import urllib2

url = "http://www.google.com/"
try:
  result = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  my_search_function(result)
  # or perhaps my_search_function(result.content)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
handleError(e)
```

Then you can just define `my_search_function(text)` to do what you need

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I presume the "urlopen" function fetches the entire page?  I have already developed methods myself which fetch the page and search for the phrase.  What I am trying to avoid though is actually fetching the entire page to my server (bandwidth issues).